# A proof for the existence of a global minimizer

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I wanted to see if my proof of the following theorem is correct.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $D$, a subset of the Euclidean space, is closed and that all the sublevel sets of the continuous real valued function $f$ on $D$ are bounded. Show that $f$ has a global minimizer.

**Proof.** Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f$ does not have a global minimizer. So, $\forall x_k\in D$, $\exists \ x_{k+1}$ such that $f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k)$. We can then construct a decreasing sequence $\{f(x_k)\}$ on $D$. Since $f$ and $D$ are bounded, $\exists x^*$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x_k) = f(x^*)$. If $x^*\in D$, we have achieved the desired contradiction. If not, $x^*$ must be on the boundary of $D$. But then since $f$ is decreasing, $\forall x_k$ we can choose $\epsilon <|x_k-x_k^*|$ such that $B_\epsilon(x_k)\subset D$. This contradicts $D$ being closed.

Comment: What is $\mathbf E$? Anyway, it seems to me that you have to extract a subsequence from $x_k$

Comment: Euclidean space. I'll add it to the theorem.

Comment: Ok. I don't think you need to distinguish between $D$ and its boundary, since $D$ is closed. However, it is important to remark that you extracted a subsequence, using the fact that in Euclidean space closed and bounded sets are compact.

Comment: Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: This seems to be false for $D=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=-x^2$. If $D$ is also assumed to be bounded, then $D$ is compact and you don't need the hypothesis on the level sets.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is broken in so many ways

1. $f(x_{k+1})\le f(x_k)$ does not imply anything (after all $(f(x_k))$ can be constant)
2. you get $x_k\to x^*$ and $f(x_k) \to f(x^*)$ only after extracting a subsequence
3. $x^*\in D$ is no contraction to anything
4. $x^*\not\in D$ does not imply $x^*\in \partial D$, $D$ is closed so $\partial D\subset D$
5. $f$ is not decreasing
6. what is $x_k^*$?
7. such an $\epsilon$ does not exist if $x_k$ is itself at the boundary of $D$
8. Wow

You can compare your 'proof' to a proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass. See how such proofs obtain statements that you wanted to get in your attempt.

Edit:

9. why has $(x_k)$ a convergent subsequence? an argument is missing here.

Comment: What if i change the inequality to $f(x_{k+1})<f(x_k)$?

Comment: Your 3rd point, I meant to say that since $f(x_k)$ is strictly decreasing and is bounded below, it must converge to a point. If the point is in D then, it is a global minimizer since for every other x_k, the function value will be higher!

Comment: The condition $f(x_{k+1})<f(x_k)$ does not imply that $x^*$ is global minimizer. Take $f(x)=x^2$ and $x_k = 1+1/k$.